# Should there be a way to close a question as a duplicate of a question from another site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We had this question on [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/).

[How can I remove insulation ink from copper wire so I can weld it in place?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/35970/33)

Which is a duplicate of this question from [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

[How do you remove insulation from headphone wires?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/7489/11080)

Is there/should there be a way to close the question as a duplicate of the question from the other site?

Comment: This is a tests

Answer (score 0):

Questions often can get different answer on different sites. Just because a question has another answer on another site doesn't automatically mean that it should be closed.

Comment: While I agree this is sometimes true, in this case even the OP admits that they found the answer they were looking for.

Comment: @Tester101 since most communities with overlap have slightly different focuses, it is not common for an answer on a 2nd site to completely answer a question on the first.  So the appropriate way is to answer with a link to the other site's question (and of course proper citation) and then reword to fit the scope of the current site.